# Why would Mick betray the team?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

In episode 7 when Mick found out why he was recruited he decides to betray the team and made a deal with the pirates.

So why did Mick make a deal with the time pirates to betray the whole team, rather than just to get home and stop being a hero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of it is because, in Snart's own words:

> **Snart:** Mick runs hot. He always has.
>
> <sup>*Legends of Tomorrow* Season 1 Episode 7: "Marooned"</sup>

Mick isn't known for his sound decision-making skills; there's a reason Snart is the brains of their partnership. When he makes this decision, Mick is angry and hurt, so he lashes out.

However, there's another, more direct reason:

### Because Mick doesn't *care* about the team

At the time he was recruited by Rip Hunter, Mick Rory is *not* a team player; he makes this point to Ray in "Fail-Safe":

> **Ray:** We're supposed to be a team.
>
> **Mick:** The only team I'm on is mine and Snart's.
>
> <sup>*Legends of Tomorrow* Season 1 Episode 5: "Fail-Safe"</sup>

Ultimately, Mick doesn't care about Savage and is on the team for entirely selfish reasons, having been convinced by Snart to join with the promise of rich opportunities for theft:

> **Mick:** I have no desire to save the world. Especially 100 years after I'm dead.
>
> **Snart:** He said across time, Mick. What about the years before? Before fingerprints and surveillance cameras and DNA analysis. Why did we become criminals? Because we hate working and we love money. We could steal the Mona Lisa straight off da Vinci's easel, snatch the Hope Diamond before it was discovered. This is everything we got into thieving for in the first place. More than everything.
>
> **Mick:** You want me in, I'm in. But I'm not gonna be anyone's hero.
>
> <sup>*Legends of Tomorrow* Season 1 Episode 1: "Pilot, Part 1"</sup>

However, by this point it's become clear to him that his "partner" is more interested in Rip's cause than in his. Mick has no loyalty left to anyone on the Waverider, and has no interest in their mission.

Why, exactly, *should* he care what happens to the rest of them?

### So why not cut a more charitable deal?

Why go through the effort? The deal he makes is the simplest way to get what he wants, and has the added bonus of sticking it to the people who belittled and (in his mind) betrayed him. Remember what he says about becoming Chronos:

> **Chronos:** You think I was hunting you [Snart] and your friends because the Time Masters made me? They barely had to ask.
>
> <sup>*Legends of Tomorrow* Season 1 Episode 9: "Left Behind"</sup>

Revenge is a powerful motivator.

### So why did he pick that moment to betray them?

Emotion and bad timing.

Rip's outburst comes when Mick is in an unstable emotional state, something Sara comments on to Snart:

> **Sara:** I've seen enough to know that Mick's in a dark place.
>
> <sup>*Legends of Tomorrow* Season 1 Episode 7: "Marooned"</sup>

Rip made Mick mad; under normal circumstances, he probably could have shrugged this off. But he was already mad at Snart, and he's been questioning whether he really wants to be on the Waverider at all.

Rip's comment was just the spark Mick needed to get mad enough to do something foolish.

Comment: But he betrayed them once he found out why he was recruited

Comment: @AndrewCasali Have you heard the phrase ["the straw that broke the camel's back"](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/Straw+that+broke+the+camel%27s+back)? Anyway, see my edit. It's basically bad timing and emotional lashing-out

Comment: What did the time masters barley had to ask when he was chronos and hunting the team because the time masters made him

Comment: @AndrewCasali That sentence is meant to be understood as a response to the (rhetorical) question before it. "They barely had to ask" Mick to hunt Rip and the Waverider. The implication being that he *really* wanted to do it anyway

Comment: So the chronos  that attacked the team in 1975 was mick he dint know that he was there fighting back right

Comment: @AndrewCasali [Stop using the comments to ask new, unrelated questions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: I'm dint ask a question